# Colaboratory: how to install PyGame Learning Environment

Tags: python, linux, jupyter-notebook, reinforcement-learning, google-colaboratory

In Colaboratory, we are forced to use pip install. Some third packages such as gym, PLE, etc, their installation should be

```
git clone https://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment.git
cd PyGame-Learning-Environment/
pip install -e .
```

When I tried, here are some problems:

1) `!cd` doesn't work here. I'm still in my current folder in google drive.

2) Instead, I directly run:

```
!git clone https://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment.git 
!pip install -e PyGame-Learning-Environment
```

And it says successfully installed, but I cannot import it. I checked and it doesnt appear in the `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages`

I also checked the python by:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

which gives me: `/content`, a directory I dont understand. And obviously I cannot import the package.

What should I do?

Comment: Should you be using pip3 instead of pip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a worked example:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PsPArPkxnhCIKSFK2gDA46_vnLMc1U9z

Tips:

- Use `os.chdir` instead of `!cd`. `!` commands execute in a subshell, so their effects won't apply to subsequent commands. `os.chdir` will, however.
- You want to check `sys.path` instead of site-packages since you're installing with `-e`.
- You'll also need to install `pygame`. It looks like that's an unlisted dep.

Full install recipe:

```
import os
!git clone https://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment.git
os.chdir('PyGame-Learning-Environment')
!pip install -e .
!pip install pygame
os.chdir('/content')
```

Comment: I cannot import the module after following your steps. Any help?

Comment: from ple.games.pong import Pong results in "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ple'". Your example doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I could install like this.

```
!git clone https://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment.git
!cd PyGame-Learning-Environment/ && pip install .

!pip install -q pygame
```

It can be checked like this.

```
!pip freeze | grep ple

--- Result ---
etuples==0.3.8
multipledispatch==0.6.0
ple @ file:///content/PyGame-Learning-Environment
```

```
from ple import PLE

--- Result ---
pygame 2.1.2 (SDL 2.0.16, Python 3.7.15)
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
couldn't import doomish
Couldn't import doom
```